# Достать информацию DMI/SMBIOS из дампа bios(.bin файл) на c#

Tags: c#

Требуется достать информацию DMI/SMBIOS из дампа bios(.bin файла). Не удалось не где найти способ сделать, ходил достать DMI самого ПК, но из дампа биоса(.bin) не где нету. Надеюсь, кто-то сможет подсказать способ.

С# .netFramework

Answer (score 0):

На сайте dmtf.org имеется [спецификация](https://www.dmtf.org/sites/default/files/standards/documents/DSP0134_3.3.0.pdf) SMBIOS, а на гитхабе [сишный хидер](https://github.com/vmware/esx-boot/blob/master/uefi/edk2/MdePkg/Include/IndustryStandard/SmBios.h) с описанием структур. Кроме того имеет смысл скачать утилиту **"Read & Write Utility"**, которая может спарсить в читаемый лог весь SMBIOS-дамп. Так можно будет сравнить реальные поля, с описанием из спеки. Теперь есть все составляющие, и написать из них программу не составит особого труда:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Основная проблема достать из обычного дампа дамп smbios. Лишь в одном из 5 я смог найти SMBIOS, в других видимо оно зашифровано, но amibcp спокойно достаёт DMI.

Comment: Функция Win32-API `GetSystemFirmwareTable()` возвращает дамп системных таблиц, в том числе и SMBIOS.

Comment: GetSystemFirmwareTable() получает информацию этого пк, мне же надо получить информацию с дампа биос вообще другого пк(Платы).
Вот как пример один из дампов, из него надо вытащить "Baseboard (or Module) Information".
https://disk.yandex.ru/d/Xpt1L0reddMtiw